# Exotic weapons (in an exotic situation)

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a fairly unusual setup in my current party. We have just three players- one rogue, one oracle, and myself. The oracle's spell choices are mostly fire-based damage attacks and healing spells. Thus, I perform the roles of secondary healer, damage dealer, party tank (seriously), *and* all-around utility (e.g. illusions, buffs, etc). As a result, I've got a pretty unusual character build.

I am a 3rd level Cleric, a 3rd level Wizard (Universalist) and a 2nd level Mystic Theurge. I've ended up with some arcane armour feats and the Exotic Weapon Proficiency feat. As a Universalist, I have the ability to throw my melee weapon with my Intelligence bonus to hit, which is +5, and have it magically return to me.

Originally at 1st level, I had great fun throwing my quarterstaff at people. However as I've gained levels, this has become of reduced usefulness. So now when it's not really worth firing spells at people I just look at them with a mean glare.

I'm curious as to whether there are any *melee* weapons that can be useful in this situation. I'd be especially interested in weapons that have additional utility effects other than just damage.

Comment: Which exotic weapon are you proficient with? When you take the feat, you must pick one weapon; you aren't proficient with *all* exotic weapons.

Comment: That... is not a rule that I'm familiar with. And it certainly seems that my DM is not familiar with it either (and I have no intention of mentioning it :P). So for now, I'm going to say that it's homebrewed to be proficiency with all exotic weapons.

Comment: Could you also please be a bit more specific about what kinds of weapons you would find useful? Plenty of exotic weapons offer extra benefits (that's why they're *exotic* and, usually, require a feat per). List-style questions don't really suit the format of this site without more specific guidelines for a useful answer. I have *a couple* frame challenges in mind for this question, but no answers. Unfortunately this means, to me at least, the question could use some revisiting.

Comment: Please also see the [Pathfinder Wiki](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/), and specifically the list of [Exotic Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#weapons-exotic) and [Exotic Weapon Proficiency Feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/exotic-weapon-proficiency-combat---final). Perhaps some of your own research could help improve the question (Or even answer it!) :)